# Does the pet bedding (inside the crate) often get destroyed on arrival in the USA?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, pets, sleeping

I am importing a cat to the USA and have been told that they often destroy the bedding on arrival. Is this true?

Comment: Probably depends on what you will be using as bedding.

Comment: How are you importing? Via boat? Plane? Vehicle?

Comment: That is to ask - which border?

Comment: Flying from Australia to Nashville via plane

Comment: Just Fabric round Donut style beds

Comment: I haven't found the government/customs source but it is natural bedding (straw, hay, grass, etc.) which cannot be imported since they can harbor various plant pests. If your pet is going into quarantine, a badly-soiled bed might be an issue. What you describe should be fine.

Comment: If "they" means "the pet", it's entirely possible to find the bedding has been destroyed upon arrival.

Comment: I am referring to Q'tine destroying the bedding on arrival.

Comment: @Mel [Australia does](http://www.agriculture.gov.au/cats-dogs/quarantine-facilities-and-fees/post-entry-quarantine-facilities) but it does not seem to be the practice in the US. Is your pet going to be quarantined?